# Creating new instance of an object associated with ManagedBean

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

I am trying out a small jsf applications which displays a form about a book such as isbn, price,title, description etc. On submission, a book object is created, persisted and a list of books already in db is displayed. Here is the code for the ManagedBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class BookController implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 @EJB
 private BookEJB bookEJB;

 private Book book = new Book();
 private List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
 public BookController()
 {

 }

public String doCreateBook()
{
   bookEJB.createBook(newBook);
   bookList = bookEJB.findBooks();
   return "listBooks.xhtml";
}

public Book getBook() {
 return book;
 }

public void setBook(Book book) {
     this.book = book;
 }

public List<Book> getBookList() {
    return bookList;
}

  }
```

Since my ManagedBean has a session scope, the issue I am facing is that using the above code, only one book object remains associated with the ManagedBean for the entire session and every time the form is submitted, the same object is added to the db with the result that after a new addition, all entries in the db have attributes similar to the last submitted book because the same object is being  persisted again and again. How to solve this problem? One approach which works is to create a new Book object inside the doCreate() function and manually copy properties which is very tedious and can still result in old properties being copied to new objects. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix this would be to keep a separate managed bean to store the book data on request.

```
    @ManagedBean
    @SessionScoped
    public class BookList implements Serializable{

    @EJB
    private BookEJB bookEJB;
    private List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();         

    public List<Book> getBooks() {            
        bookList = bookEJB.findBooks();
        return bookList;
    }

    }
```

Keep a separate request scoped bean to edit , create book .

```
    @ManagedBean
    @RequestScoped
    public class BookBean implements Serializable{

    @EJB
    private BookEJB bookEJB;

    private Book book = new Book();

    public Book getBook() {
     return book;
     }

    public void setBook(Book book) {
         this.book = book;
     }


    public String createBook()
    {
       bookEJB.createBook(book);
       return "listBooks.xhtml";
    }

    }
```

And in your createBook.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"      
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <title>Create Book</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h3>Add book</h3>
        <h:form>
           <h:inputText value="#{bookBean.book.name}"></h:inputText>
           ....
           ....    

           <h:commandButton action="#{bookBean.createBook()}" 
                   value="Create Book"></h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Your list page,

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"      
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

        <h:head>
            <title>Book List</title>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <h3>Book List</h3>
            <h:dataTable value="#{bookList.books}" var="o">
                ....
                ....  

            </h:dataTable>
        </h:body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If I use RequestScope for BookBean, I get error that property BookBean needed by BookController is not available because the scope of bookBean which is Request is shorter than that of bookController which is Session

Comment: I guess the better way is to separate the functionality in two beans and access your service (EJB) from both beans . One is session scoped and other is request scoped. I have edited the code to use the service in both beans